# Occasional openssl_decrypt error : "failed to base64 decode the input"

Tags: php, openssl

I have 2 PHP pages, in which page 1 encrypt a string `onLoad`, the encrypted string would be passed over to page 2 via a URL.

Occasionally (roughly 1 out of 8) page 2 cannot decrypt the string, and gives me this error message: *`failed to base64 decode the input ...`*

And here is what I am using:

- encryption method : `AES-128-CBC`
- iv : `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);`

Here are some additional info :

- PHP 5.4.16
- nginx 1.8.0
- centos 7

Any advice please?

Comment: Sounds like a URL encoding issue to me. You could help us confirm that by providing an example of one that fails. It probably contains a `+` or `=` sign or some such, while other examples that work okay don't. It would also help if you provided the code that is being used to put the string into the URL, so we can see whether it is being encoded properly or not.

Comment: you are right, that's where the problem is.  i will include the way i solved it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include a string in an URL, you need to [URL encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) it. For base 64, you need to replace `=` with `%3D`, but don't do that. Instead, use a [proper URL encoding function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) when you include a string in an URL.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the rawurlencode / rawurldecode functions which i have no such an idea before ( ... '_'; )~

Comment: I believe he could also use Base64 with the Web Safe alphabet from [RFC 4648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#page-7). Standards like Jason Web Keys (JWK) use the alphabet. OpenSSL uses the original Base64 alphabet, and not the web safe one. So he will need an encoding function if he wants to continue using OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the comments from @Simba & @David Schwartz, here's what should be done :

on page 1 :

```
 - encrypt the string via openssl_encrypt();
 - encode the encrypted string for sending via url by rawurlencode();
 - concatenate those "encrypted+encoded" strings and send via url;
```

on page 2 :

```
 - take the var out from $_GET;
 - decode the var via rawurldecode();
 - decrypt the decoded var via openssl_decrypt();
```

works properly now ~ thx again~